# How do I pass content of variables from one notebook to another in a databricks workflow?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am looking for a way to access data from other notebooks in a Databricks Workflow.

Meaning. I have some results in Notebook A and Notebook B that depends on Notebook A. Notebook B wants to access the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing this question, the Workflows in Databricks are one year old.

It seems there is no way at the time of writing this by Databricks

https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001kL6tpCAC/how-to-pass-outputs-from-a-python-task-to-a-notebook-task.

And the only way to do it would be to store it in a DB table

Answer (score 3):

It seems this is now possible using the feature *task values* ([announcement](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/08/02/sharing-context-between-tasks-in-databricks-workflows.html), [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#taskvalues-subutility-dbutilsjobstaskvalues)).

This feature is useful to pass variables from a parent task to its childs. If you want to pass huge amounts of data between notebooks, I am afraid you need to write them anywhere else, as [@Stefan Papp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453623/stefan-papp) suggests.

Comment: True, still it is not possible to pass tables between tasks, though this can be very useful.